# Does openhtmltopdf support external css

Tags: java, openhtmltopdf

Im converting an Html to pdf using openhtmltopdf java but it doesn't apply external CSS I want to know whether this library has the support for external CSS.

Answer (score 0):

i think openhtmltoPdf not support external css but you can add styles in html page

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference your css in the html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{css/Layout.css}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable external css files you need to provide the base address.
So something like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Changes to something like this

```html
<base href="localhost:4200">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Works like a charm for me.

Answer (score 0):

In know the question is more than 3 years old. But I had the same issue and found a solution.

I'm using openhtmltopdf-pdfbox 1.0.10 with the `PdfRendererBuilder` like this:

```
try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/demo.pdf")) {
    PdfRendererBuilder builder = new PdfRendererBuilder();
    builder.useFastMode();
    builder.withUri("classpath:demo.html");
    builder.toStream(os);
    builder.run();
}
```

The file demo.html contains a link to a CSS resource in the `head` section:

```
<head>
    <link href="classpath:html-to-pdf.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
</head>
```

Comment: Does this allow for multiple css embeded in the Header as links... and does it work with multiple links?